# How Spartacus avoid loading of library specific services in main bundle?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, spartacus-storefront

I am new to Spartacus(4.0.0). I don't understand how Spartacus loading the singleton services in lazy loaded modules without injecting them into root. I read many articles about lazy loading. I did not find any method to inject singleton service into the application without using forRoot() or provideIn: root.

Can anyone help me to understand how Spartacus handling the services in lazy loaded modules?
If I am not able to explain my question properly then please let me know.

I want to understand the implementation of services in Spartacus lazy loaded module.